# What is best way to using Elastic search for searching (Via Server vs Direct Java Client)?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am new to **Elasticsearch**. I want to store documents of products details. Now I am using **Mongodb** as my database and **nodejs** server. But Mongodb does not have good search functionalities like Elasticsearch.

So I am thinking of shifting to ES. But I have few doubts as stated below please suggest me what should I do. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

1. Should I use MongoDb as my primary database for storing documents and ES as secondary database just for doing efficient search. Or Should I make ES as my only database for storing documents and searching.
2. Does using both will be good for future or it will make thing difficult to manage. I have also read that ES in not a good choice for main database as it sometimes loses write operation.
3. Should I make a server in nodejs to perform ES operations for doing any complex search or GET, PUT using rest api or should I do it directly implement it in java .

**(Note I am making a android app so should I use TransportClient and Interact with Elasticsearch directly or I should first send a GET request from android side to my server and my nodejs server will interact with ES and send response to my android app)**.

4. Other than search part is ES performs as good as MondoDb in terms of Database.

   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am risking an opinionated answer here. However I'll try to help you out:

1. I am using elasticsearch as a primary data store in cases the data is not that important or just to big to have it duplicated. If you have things like logs you could also keep the original logs files around. By default I would say, use a different database as primary store, that way you can always rebuild elastic if you want to make changes to your search index.
2. Adding components to your infrastructure makes it more work to manage. So adding MongoDB as well as Elastic does mean more moving parts. However, it also gives you more flexibility. I would not be to much afraid unless what you are searching for is very basic and can be done with MongoDB as well.
3. I advice to always have an application in front of your search engine. Treat it like a database, you would not expose that to the world.
4. I would not use a Transport Client in your Android app. That would mean a security risk. You want to make a connection to your backend as mentioned in 3 and let that application connect to your search cluster.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for help. 1)What do you mean by in case data is not important. I have to store products details like name, price, brand so its important. 2)And you want me to use node js server which will interacts with ES. 3)And one more thing, Do I need to copy the all the mondodb documents to ES so just the fields which I want to search(i.e projecting only fileds I want to search). 4)Can you guide me how do we copy mongodb documnets to ES for first time and how do we select fields I want to index and rebuild them. Thanks

Comment: 1) Not important, as in not a real problem if you loose it. 2) Yes, or any other backend you are comfortable with 3) Just the fields you want to search 4) A lot of documentation available. Usually I just send the docs I send to Mongo also to elastic. Have a look at this: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector